# Table Structure for Tableau

Tags: charts, data-visualization, pie-chart, tableau-api

I have a query regarding the table structure for the pie chart on Tableau.

I have below 2 table structures and am not sure which one is more apt for tableau to arrive at a pie chart .

For example I wish to see the percentage of each metric over a particular date contributing towards the total. May be the representation is a pie chart or some other chart. Please suggest me which table lay out works out well for my requirement.

Note : I have done all my calculations to arrive at the total in my database table itself.

Could some one please help me out.Thanks!

Table 1 : 
[image]

Table2 :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Pie charts first take a series of data and sum the total. Then they calculate the percent of each element of the series and create a pie slice with a unique color. To make a pie chart, you need one measure (the category or label) and one dimension (the amount of that category).

If you need to see how one is made, I would suggest downloading an example workbook and then going to the pie chart sheet. One example is [here](http://www.tableausoftware.com/about/blog/2012/7/one-potential-reason-use-pie-chart-18482).

Here is how it looks when set up in Tableau.

[image]

**Personal note:** Despite the name, pie charts are not that delicious. [Here is advice from Tableau themselves](https://www.tableausoftware.com/public/community/best-practices/pie-chart). And [here is something](http://prezi.com/hq2s8kwz9-zk/pie-chart-fan-club) I made up to express my feelings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If not pie chart what I should be using in order to represent my individual metric contributions to the overall total.Because right now am summing up the total on the database side to make tableau reporting light and quick

Comment: There is a time and a place for everything, including pie charts. The problem with pie charts is that you lose the overall total, since the data is reduced to percents of total.

Comment: ok. to make it simple my requirement is like . I have c = a*b. lets assume c is the total value . I am trying to visualize 'c' as a relation of a and b and the contribution from each of them in the value of c.Which is the best chart i can use for this.

Comment: if c is a*b, then it's not the sum. for a pie chart you would need c = a + b. Then the slice for *a* would have the area a/c, or a/(a+b), which is the fraction of the total.

Comment: bullet charts are a good way to show an individual contribution towards a total

Answer (score 0):

Relating to the topic of pie charts, and how to best represent data where contributions to a whole are of interest, I would recommend bullet graphs as well. Here are two papers by Stephen Few that could be of interest:

Save the Pies for Dessert
http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/08-21-07.pdf

Bullet Graph Design Specification
http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/misc/Bullet_Graph_Design_Spec.pdf

And, to answer your question on data preparation for Tableau, it looks like the second table would be more appropriate. Here's a good KB for preparing data for analysis, note the last section on the Tableau Reshaper tool for Excel...can save a ton of time.

Preparing Excel Files for Analysis
http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/preparing-excel-files-analysis